# Best way to plot horizontal data and see it clearly?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have my `dataframe` object `df` which looks like this:

```
   product   7.month    8.month     9.month     10.month    11.month    12.month    1.month     2.month     3.month     4.month     5.month     6.month
0   phone      68         137         202         230          143        220         110        173          187         149         204          90
1   television  <same kind of numerical data>
2
3
4
...
```

I would like to plot this data, but I'm not sure how to plot this, because months are `horizontal` (columns) and also have around 20 `products` (rows) in my dataframe, so people could read from it

Answer (score 0):

Transpose the dataframe

```
df1 = df.T
```

and now plot df1

Answer (score 0):

I agree and recommend [Aavesh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13960989/aavesh) approach. However, if it is absolutely necessary to access the data horizontally, then you can use `list(df.iloc[index])` where `index` is the index of the row.

Then plot.